# Find the longest string of words such that the (4 letter) end of one word is the start of the next

Tags: word, language, open-ended, letters, no-computers

Here is an open-ended challenge.

Find the longest series of English words such that the final four letters of word $n$ are the same as the first four letters of word $n+1$.

**Example**

(3 words) quintu**plet** plet**hora** horary

At that point I stopped because I could find no dictionary words beginning with 'rary'.

**Rules**

1. Only words that are defined in [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/) are allowed. Plurals and verb conjugation are allowed. If a word is doubtful then the community will decide by their votes.
2. No repeats. No word must appear more than once in a list.
3. Four letter words are allowed. But if you use one then it must be the last in the list.
4. Before posting, check the longest answer so far. If you cannot do better then please don't post. This prevents many equal answers.
5. If by chance two or more people post equal solutions at the same time then the one that is earliest on the SE system clock is counted and the others are not. As a courtesy, please delete your answer if you were beaten time-wise. If it is a dead-heat by the system clock then the answers will be considered equal.

5a. If by examining someone else's answer you are able to improve it by inserting one or more words then this is allowed and you may give it as a separate answer. Note that the consensus from reading other peoples' comments is that this is disapproved of. If you do it you may get down-voted unless you can justify it to the community.

4. Please give your answer in the following format so that others can easily see what they have to beat.

**Answer format**

(3 words) quintuplet plethora horary

Comment: are plurals allowed?

Comment: Yes, I've added to rule 1.

Comment: Okay - I've changed the rule. It seems better if four letter words are allowed in the middle.

Comment: Is the 4-letter chunk allowed to be repeated (as in "turnover overturn"), just not the whole word?

Comment: @randal'thor - That looks fine to me. It is only the whole word that must not be repeated.

Comment: Please note that I have added rule 5a. It doesn't change anything, it's just a clarification.

Comment: This might get a little *too* open-ended if 4 letter words are allowed. You could easily get at least another 20 words into rand al'thor's list, for example

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat makes a good point: as Kingrames said on my answer, any list could be made almost twice as long by just adding in 4-letter words. Maybe you *should* only allow them at the ends after all?

Comment: Okay - Once again I bow to peer pressure. Let's revert to my original rule.

Comment: I was suggesting start *or* end being OK for 4-letter words, but never mind

Comment: I say you should get bonus points if the 4 letter word at the start would match the end, to form a loop.

Comment: I am staunchly against rule 5a. Because right now @randal'thor is working on his list and has reached 49 words (at the time of this comment). Maybe he will reach 100 and then stop. And then someone comes along tomorrow and adds his own answer by inserting one word somewhere between rand's list, and that's a valid strategy? Hardly seems fair.

Comment: @CodeNewbie - Your view seems to be that of the majority. I've edited 5a accordingly.

Comment: I really don't wanna be "that guy", but this is one of those questions, that are too easily solved by a machine. The dumbest brute-forcing approach yielded a chain of length 885 pretty fast.

Comment: Select the word with the  4-letter ending that starts the largest number of other words, rinse and repeat, each time ignoring words chosen earlier.

Comment: Having seen @dmg's comment ... quick, add a [no-computers] tag!!

Comment: @dmg - Did you read them all from dictionary.com? If not, have you checked they are all valid?

Comment: @randal'thor -  Haha! Done.

Comment: How would you know if a computer was used though ;)

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah - If the full text from dictionary.com isn't available online and your list contains several/many words that aren't in that dictionary, that is a good clue that someone has been cheating. If you can find a readable list that is a subset of dictionary.com then I suppose it is impossible to prove anything. In that case no-one can prevent you offering it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know if there's a list or not, but I assume any standard dictionary 's world list would be a subset of that in dictionary.com, but you don't even need a list, you can just query dictionary.com for each word to check they have a page for it.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK The wordlist I tried contains a mere ~110 000 words (in comparison, most self-respecting English dictionaries contain about ~500 000). Validating such a chain against Dictionary.com is a tedious, but trivial task for anyone who is interested. I took a look at a bunch of random words from it and they all checked out.

Comment: So post your 885 word list and we can check it.

Comment: @dmg - Okay. It would be up to you to do the tedious checking. Otherwise you might get down-voted by the community if they found a single exception.  Here's my suggestion - Submit your answer (via a URL if necessary) and clearly mark it as computer-generated. Say what your source text is. Then we can run a simultaneous competition for the best computer version and others can see if they can beat it with a better program.

Comment: Why does a four letter word need to be at the end of the list? What about something like: platform -> form -> formation  ?

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah - This was debated in comments. It makes the task too easy. It is an arbitrary rule that is there to limit the possible answers.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK oh, yes, sorry, I missed that.

Comment: @Kingrames - Following your suggestion, if I could start again, I think I would make it a condition that *all* sequences should make a loop.  Even better if the start and finish had to be the same four-letter word!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Firstly, I'm not planning on submitting it as it is clearly not the way you intended this puzzle to be solved. I was merely pointing out a flaw in this and in most word puzzles in general. Secondly, this problem is technically a classic graph theory problem - [Longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) (a quite hard problem, BTW). Thirdly, the quality of the solutions is basically a matter of the quality of the dictionary, which makes the problem less interesting from an algorithmic POV.

Comment: @dmg - No worries. I might submit a slightly modified (and hopefully harder) version where computers are allowed. As you say, the algorithm isn't trivial.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Also, there are 5 public dictionary APIs (that I found in 2 minutes), chances are they will filter most of the issues.

Comment: @dmg - Next puzzle I submit will have to have some restriction that makes it difficult for computer search!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK As long as words are looked upon as mere sequences of characters (that is, their meaning is disregarded), computers will (almost) always have the upper hand.

Comment: Seems to me it would be a better puzzle if there were a restriction disallowing the use of the same four-letter link more than once.  So that a sequence like this would be forbidden: makeover overturn turnover overcome

Comment: I think the [no-computer] tag in this question has different usage to other questions that used the tag. The tag seems to be made for questions that do not require (not "do not allow") computers in order to get the answer. But it's only a thin line separating them, I think.

Comment: To @dennisdeems' point, see my free list of words commented on rand's post. It almost seemed like cheating. Also, regarding checking your dictionary against dictionary.com, I pruned a list of 26k words (length 5-8) in ~3.5 hours on a decent laptop so it's certainly feasible.

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah in regards to your comment about dictionary.com and wordlists: I have found that most wordlists are in fact a *superset* of dictionary.com, which frustrates me to no end.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019 (and since this is explicitly no-computers, brute-force "optimization" isn't allowed)

Comment: @chasly I don't remember solving this one but I seriously doubt I did it without computer assistance.  I suggest unaccepting my answer so I can delete it.

Comment: This could be interesting (and difficult for computers) to add the restriction that the words must for a grammatically correct sentence. Perhaps the letter overlap should be reduced then too.

Comment: @MatthewJensen it would still be open-ended and off-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This answer previously had a solution probably found by computer search)

Comment: I *did* use a computer to verify that all of the words are on Dictionary.com.

Comment: If you came up with this list without using a computer, I don't know whether to give you a medal or tell you to get a life! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I have too much schoolwork to do this completely by hand; no medal for me I'm afraid =P

Answer (score 24):

(4 words) monopoly polymath mathematically allying

(8 words) sleepover overwork workshop shoplift liftoffs offside sideburn burnout

**(123 words) thigh highjack jackboot, bootstrap trapdoor doorstep stepbrother therein, reinterpret preterm termini minidrama ramada, madam adamant mantram tramp rampart, partake takeover overflow flowering ringside, sidestep stepmother there heretofore forevermore, moreover overfree freeform formant mantrap, trapdoor doorbell bellpull pullover overturn, turnover overwork workshop shoplift liftoffs, offspring ringtone toneless lessens sensitising, singsong songbird birdsong songbook bookkeepers, persistent tenterhook hooking kinglike likelihood, hoodwink winking kingship shipload loadmaster, stereotype typewriter iterant ranting tingling, lingering ringworm wormwood woodworm wormhole, holeless lessons sonship shipwreck reckoner, onerous rousing singalong longhorn hornbeam, beamish mishmash mashing hinge ingest, gesticulate latewood woodcock cockpits pitstop, stopping pinging gingerbread readership shipyard, yardland landlord lordship shipment mentoring, ringneck necklace lacewing wingspan spanking, kingfisher sherlock lockdown downside sidelong, longboat boatfuls fulsome somewhere herein, reinforcement menthol tholepins pinstripe riper**

<sub>(commas every 5 words, to make the count easier)</sub>

Thanks to all those who helped me with this, including Kingrames, Anachor, Gordon K, Code Newbie, Rj Geraci, and others.

Comment: change long to longing and then ginger or something else dunno. Or longest and gesture... dunno. Cool stuff.

Comment: Woh, lots of comments deleted! Apologies to those of you who helped me out with parts of the answer - I can't remember who you all were. Anachor, GordonK, CodeNewbie, ...?

Comment: Why not isentropic?

Comment: Man you nuked our comments from orbit! I suppose I'll just be one of "the others" then, LOST-style. ;)

Comment: @Kingrames Sorry! How could I forget you? :-)

Comment: ripens instead of riper opens up to pens... which not sure pensive is productive or pension... not sure trying to avoid dictionaries personally lol.

Comment: You can extend any of the gaps between "...over" and "over...." with the following (and any others like them): overhand handover overpass passover overhang hangover overhung hungover overslip slipover overtake takeover overturn turnover overstep stepover

Comment: Add to the above string: overhear heart earthmover

Comment: @NeedAName That's **Evil**.

Comment: @Goinghamateur ripens / pensive / sivers / versions / ions

Comment: Maybe replace "riper" with "ripest" and continue with "pesticide", "cider" (or other word that allows you to continue). Also, you've got at least one repeated word (trapdoor appears more than once for example).

Answer (score 21):

From exchange to <strike>stack</strike> overflow:

(45 words) exch**ange** -> angel**fish** -> fish**bone** -> bone**meal** -> meal**time** -> time**line** -> linea**ment** -> menta**list** -> list**less** -> les**sons** -> son**ship** -> ship**side** -> side**walk** -> walky**ries** -> ries**ling** -> lingui**stic** -> stick**ball** -> ball**game** -> game**play** -> play**mate** -> mate**ship** -> ship**yard** -> yard**land** -> land**lord** -> lor**ding** -> din**ging** -> gingerb**read** -> read**just** -> justi**fies** -> fi**esta** -> establi**sher** -> sher**lock** -> lock**step** -> stepfa**ther** -> there**fore** -> fo**rest** -> res**tack** -> tac**king** -> king**fish** -> fish**tail** -> tail**race** -> race**mism** -> mis**move** ->  m**over** -> overflow

Comment: Nice one (and welcome to Puzzling.SE!) I've managed to beat it with 39 though :-)

Comment: Thanks ;-) Unfortunatelly my lunch break was over, so I had to stop. Maybe I'll continue tonight.

Comment: In the last word you used 5 letters from the previous word. You ended up at tack, not stack.

Comment: Is that an overflow ? :o)

Comment: @CodeNewbie, you are right, I fixed it. All the way to overflow

Comment: @Christoph - and of course you can continue from there if you so wish :-)

Comment: It was more entertaining than I thought it would be, but quite time consuming as well. So my plan is to expand it all the way to armada and then just attach rand al'thor's list, haha ;-)

Comment: @Christoph - I think you have a moving target. :-)

Answer (score 20):

I think I have finally locked myself in at **174 words:**

**thigh, highjack, jackboot, bootstrap, trapdoor, doorstep, stepbrother, therein, reinterpret, preterm, termini, minidrama, ramada, madam, adamant, manta, antacid, acidifies, fiesta, establishment, mentalist, listen, stench, enchantment, menthols, holster, stereotype, typecast, castaways, wayside, sidearm, earmark, markdown, downcast, caste, aster, stertorous, rousing, singletons, tonsure, surefire, firearm, earmarking, kingpins, pinstripe, ripest, pestering, ringlike, likelihood, hoodwink, winking, kingship, shipload, loadstar, starch, archbishop, shopkeepers, persecute, cutest, testament, mentoring, ringside,sidecars, carsick, sickbeds, bedside, sidekick, kickback, backbone, bonehead, headband, bandanna, annalist, listens, tense, ensembles, blessing, singletree, treed, reedit, editorship, shipmate, materialising, singsong, songbird, birdbath, bathe, atheistic, stickleback, backdate, dateline, lineage, eagerest, restaff, taffrail, railroad, roadbeds, bedsore, sorehead, headgear, gearing, ringworm, wormwood, woodblock, lockouts, outscore, corespondent, dentistry, strychnine, ninepin, epinephrins, rinse, inseam, seamanship, shippers, perseverance, ancestor, storage, rageless, lessees, seesawing, wingspan, spanking, kingfishers, herself, selfish, fishbowl, bowlfuls, fulsome, somebody, bodysuit, suitcase, casein, seiner, inerrant, ranting, tinge, ingest, gestapos, apostleship, shipwreck, reckless, lessens, sensationalist, listener, enervating, tinging, gingerbread, readdressing, singe, ingesting, tingling, lingering, ringing, gingersnap, snapdragon, agonizing, zinging, ginghams, hamster, sterling, linguistic, stick, ticking, kingfisher, sheriff, riffing, fingering, ringmaster, sternest, nestling, linguines, inescapable, abled, bled**

Thanks to rand al'thor, Ian MacDonald, and Anachor for the help!

Comment: Sorry, "correspondent" is mis-spelled and this invalidates the link.

Comment: Actually it isn't. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/corespondent?s=t Though I have to confess, I wasn't expecting that to be a real word!

Comment: OK, my mistake! +1 then, although I've just beaten you with 104 :-)

Comment: You can start like the other sequence and continue with a`rageless` which opens up more possibilities.

Comment: This isn't over yet @randal'thor!

Comment: With two more: abled, bled.

Comment: ablest -> lestobiotic -> otic

Comment: If you can get to something involving 'over' without costing too much (ie <=15), you can take advantage of a string of "free" words that I added in a comment on rand's answer. (free here meaning that they put you back where you started but with a bump in word count)

Comment: Take off the first couple words and put in http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overboot instead?

Comment: You could replace "thigh" with "overtake, takeover, overhang, hangover, overhigh" which leads into highjack. You could say that was ... overdone? over the top? game over? okay I'll stop...

Answer (score 12):

350 and counting :)

highball balladeer deerflys flyspeck pecking kingfish fishable ables bless lessees seesawing wingback backache aches chestfuls fulsome somebody bodybuilding dinging gingerbread readapting tinge ingest gestapos apostasies siesta establisher sherbert berthing hinge ingestant tantalic alice licence enceinte integrate raters tersest sestet stethoscope copenhagen agency encyclic cliches chestier tiering ringbolt bolthead headaches chestnuts nutshell hellbent benthal thalami lamia amias miasmas smash masher sherd herdswomen omens menschen chenille illegal egalite liter iterant ranting tinging gingering ringdove dover overabundance ancestor storables blessedest destain tainting tingling lingering ringing gingersnap snapback backbencher cherish rishis shist histamin amino minoring ringlike likelihood hoodless lessens sensate sateen teener energizing zinging ginghams hamster stereochemistry strychnine ninefold foldboat boatbill billeter eterne ernest nester stereoscope coper opera peradventure tureen reenactment mentalist listen stench enchainment menthol thole holeless lessons sonships hipshot shotguns gunship shipload loadstar starch archaistic stick ticking kingfisher sheriff riffing fingering ringmaster stereoscopy copybook bookcase casebook bookend kendo endomorph orphan phantast taste aster stereotape tapeline lineage eagerest restack tackifies fiesta establishment menthols holster stereotype typebars barstool toolhead headachier hierarch archbishop shope hoper operandi andiron ironbark barkeep keepers persecute cutest testament mentioner onerous rousing singletons tonsorial rialto altogether therapist pistil stilbestrol troll rollback backbenchers herself selfheal healer alertest testee steeling linguistic sticking kingpins pinscher cherisher sherlock locking kingship shipmaster stereotypers persevering ringneck neckband bandanna annalist listens tense ensembles blessing singletree treed reedit edith dither there hereabout boutiques quester sternest nestlike likest kestrel trellising singsong songbird birdbath bathe atheistic stickleback backbone boneblack lackeyed eyedroppers persimmons monseigneur neurogram grammars marseille illegitimate materialist lister stertorous roustabout bouts outscore corelate lateen teenyboppers persist sisterhood hoodwink winking kingside sidearm earmark markdown downcast castaways wayside sideband bandoleer leering ringside sideburn burnouts outscoring ringtail tailbone bonefish fishbone bonehead headband bandwagon agonise niseis seismicity cityward wardens dense enserfing fingernail nailhead headgear gearcase caseload loadstone tones oneself selfhood hoodwinking kingwood woodblock lockouts outsell sellout louts outsets setscrew crewelwork workboat boatswain wainscot scotland landfall fallback backdate dateline linear nearest restaff taffrail railbird birdbrain rainbows bowshot shots hotshots hotspur spurge urgency encyclopedic edict dictaphone honest nestor store toreador adoring ringtoss tosspot spots potshard hardback backdoor doorbell belletristic stickouts outshone honeycomb combatant tantalum alumina minacity citywide widely...

Comment: Pretty good answer, but the question states "no computers". (I do think that that's an unreasonable restriction though.)

Comment: Oops ! You are right I cheated! I had fun to buid up this little program, though. I'm sorry, please all feel free to get inspired by this answer =)

Comment: You don't need to apologize! Hope to see you around on Puzzling.SE more often!

Comment: @Deusovi what if I don't use a computer, but I use an answer of someone that did? (But then again, how did I post an answer if I didn't use a computer?)

Answer (score 3):

(4 words) building ding dinge inge

(13 word) backdoor doorpost postface facedown downspouts 
outsprang rangeland landmass masacres crescendo 
endocardial Dialogues Guesswork workmate material 
rialto altocumulus ulus

Comment: hope the answer is in a correct way :)

Comment: @randal'thor so you mean that a 4 letter word cant be in the middle? Then there can be only maximum one word and it has to be at end?

Comment: I'm not sure. The OP says words can't be repeated, therefore 4-letter words can only be at the end; but that logic seems to be wrong.

Comment: I too believe OP is incorrect in his logic. The example of "building ding dinge" seems completely appropriate. I'd frown on something like "takeover over overtake take taken", I don't think that's in the spirit of it. But with ding being so different from the other words, that seems completely legit.

Comment: I agree with the OP.  There is no need for the intermediary "ding" to link bulding and dinge, and in a puzzle what is unnecessary is de trop.

Answer (score 3):

A very similar puzzle to this was [posted on PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44922/building-a-long-chain-of-words), and I answered it, but it's significantly harder with an overlap of four letters instead of three. I modified my code from that problem (after digging through old files to find it and fixing some bugs), and, after a few minutes, I got this chain of length 300:

Aachen -> chenille -> illegitimate -> materialistic -> stick -> tick -> tickling -> linguistic -> stickpins -> pins -> pinstripe -> ripens -> pens -> pensioner -> onerous -> rousing -> singletons -> tonsuring -> ringside -> sidetrack -> racketeering -> ring -> ringmaster -> sterling -> lingering -> ringing -> gingerbread -> readjust -> justifies -> fiestas -> stashed -> shed -> shedding -> dinging -> gingersnap -> snap -> snappers -> persecute -> cutest -> test -> tester -> sternest -> nesting -> tinge -> ingest -> gesticulate -> late -> latent -> tenth -> enthronement -> mentoring -> ringworm -> wormwood -> wood -> woodwork -> workmanlike -> like -> likewise -> wisecracking -> kingship -> shippers -> persist -> sisterhood -> hoodwinking -> kingfishers -> herself -> selfish -> fisher -> sheriff -> riffraff -> raffish -> fish -> fishtail -> tailgate -> gate -> gatepost -> poster -> stereotype -> typeface -> facet -> acetaminophen -> phenomenons -> nonsupport -> portables -> blessing -> sing -> singsong -> songbird -> birdwatcher -> cheroot -> root -> rootless -> lessens -> sensationalist -> listens -> tense -> ensembles -> bless -> less -> lessees -> seesawing -> wing -> wingspread -> readership -> shipload -> load -> loadstar -> star -> starch -> archdeacons -> consign -> sign -> signpost -> postmark -> markdown -> down -> downwind -> windmill -> millipede -> pedestal -> stalwart -> wartime -> timekeepers -> perseverance -> ancestry -> strychnine -> nineteenth -> enthusiastic -> stickleback -> backfire -> firetrap -> trapdoor -> doorways -> ways -> wayside -> sideshows -> hows -> howsoever -> ever -> everybody -> body -> bodywork -> workbook -> bookkeepers -> persimmons -> monstrous -> roustabout -> bout -> bouts -> outs -> outstrip -> trip -> tripled -> pled -> pledge -> edgewise -> wise -> wiseacres -> crescent -> cent -> centigram -> gramophone -> honeymoon -> moonstruck -> rucksack -> sackfuls -> fulsome -> somewhere -> heretofore -> forestall -> tall -> tallyhoed -> hoedown -> downcast -> cast -> castor -> storybook -> book -> bookcase -> casework -> work -> workshop -> shoplift -> liftoffs -> offs -> offside -> sidewalk -> walkouts -> outspread -> read -> readouts -> outside -> sideline -> linemen -> emend -> mend -> mendicant -> cant -> cantilever -> evermore -> moreover -> overkill -> killdeer -> deerskin -> skin -> skinhead -> headword -> word -> wordplay -> play -> playback -> backstairs -> airsick -> sickbeds -> beds -> bedsore -> sore -> sorehead -> head -> headline -> line -> linefeed -> feed -> feedback -> backside -> sideshow -> showdown -> downhill -> hillock -> lockstep -> stepbrother -> therein -> rein -> reinterpret -> pretend -> tend -> tenderfoot -> foot -> footstep -> stepmother -> therapist -> pistons -> tons -> tonsure -> sure -> surefire -> fireside -> sidekick -> kickback -> backhand -> hand -> handpick -> pickaback -> back -> backstops -> topsoil -> soil -> soils -> oils -> oilskin -> skins -> kinswomen -> omens -> menswear -> wearisome -> somewhat -> what -> whatever -> everywhere -> here -> herewith -> with -> withhold -> hold -> holdover -> overland -> landlady -> ladybird -> bird -> birdbath -> bathes -> thespian -> pianissimi -> simile -> milepost -> posture -> tureen -> reenlist -> listen -> stenches -> chestnuts -> nuts -> nutshell -> hell -> hellion -> lion -> lionizing -> zing -> zinging -> gingersnaps -> naps

Comment: You have a lot of 4 letter words. **tick, pins pens, ring, shed, snap, test**... These are invalid as per rule 3. Only the last word **snap** is a valid four letter word, given the rules.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I didn't notice that rule. I have modified my program and am generating a valid sequence now.

Comment: @KSFT note the **no computers** tag

Comment: @KSFT: And you still have 4-letter word inside (cent, cast, sign, offs, back, sure, and many others)

Comment: @justhalf I had some problems with my computer. I'm about to generate a valid sequence.

Comment: Actually you can just remove those 4-letter words, since they can be removed while keeping the chain valid.